# How to add, view, sort data from models or db on GMT week number basis

Tags: python, django

Please guide me im new to django i want to display and add data on week number basis

For ex GMT week starts on Sunday and ends Saturday so only current week data should be shown but should be able to retrieve past weeks data as wel kind

Select Week [2021-30] 30th week of year 2021

So how to write the logic to display data stored in db fetching creation date or updation date